# NSRangeException, reason: 'Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds...'

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsrangeexception

Got a UITableView that I'm populating with ChatMessage objects, that I keep in a Dictionary that is grouped by date sent like so `var groupedMessages = [Date : [ChatMessage]]()`
I'm also keeping keys in `var keys = [Date]()`

Setting sections and dequeueing into rows works just fine.
Also `insertRows` below works and adds the message as a new UITableViewCell as expected and at the correct position.

However, the App crashed at the `scrollToRow` call with error `NSRangeException, reason: 'Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds row (2) when there are only 2 rows in section 1.`

```swift
    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {

            // create new ChatMessage object
            var newMessage = ChatMessage()
            let now = Date()
            newMessage.tsp = now
            newMessage.message = self.MessageTextField.text
            newMessage.sender = Globals.shared.user

            // append to grouped messages
            self.groupedMessages[self.keys.last!]?.append(newMessage)
            var path = IndexPath(row: self.groupedMessages[self.keys.last!]!.count-1, section: self.keys.count-1)
            print("PATH: ", path)
            self.MessageList.beginUpdates()
            self.MessageList.insertRows(at: [path], with: .fade)
            print("PATH 2: ", path)
            self.MessageList.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            self.MessageList.endUpdates()

            // call api to store sent message
            ...

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forget to **add delegate, and datasource** of table view. After adding this, my code started working.

This error occurs because your table is not able to find the data or cell.

Answer (score -2):

The problem I had was that I tried to scroll before finishing the update.
Corrected code:

```swift
// append to grouped messages
        self.groupedMessages[self.keys.last!]?.append(newMessage)
        var path = IndexPath(row: self.groupedMessages[self.keys.last!]!.count-1, section: self.keys.count-1)
        self.MessageList.beginUpdates()
        self.MessageList.insertRows(at: [path], with: .fade)
        self.MessageList.endUpdates()
        self.MessageList.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: Delete both lines `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` anyway. They have no effect around a single `insert` operation. And please conform to the naming convention and name variables and functions with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: @vadian: thanks for your input. Got another question around that code section here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865792/problem-with-row-insertion-in-a-uitableview Would really appreciate your help there as I'm stuck and can't seem to get out